# On the integral $\int_0^\pi\sin(x\sin(x\sin(x\cdots)))\,dx$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

This is a follow-up question to the one with [addition instead of multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944265/on-the-integral-int-0-pi-sinx-sinx-sinx-cdots-dx/2944309#2944309).

> Consider $f_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f_2(x)=\sin(xf_1(x))$ such that $f_n$ satisfies the relation $$f_n(x)=\sin(xf_{n-1}(x)).$$ To what value does $$L:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\pi f_n(x)\,dx$$ converge, where it exists?
>
> If it does not exist, what are the values of $$L_e:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\pi f_{2k}(x)\,dx,\quad L_o:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\pi f_{2k-1}(x)\,dx$$ for $k=1,2,\cdots$?

The following diagram shows the values of $L_i$ for even and odd $i$. The odd $i$ all have $x$-coordinate $0.2$ and the even $i$ all have $x$-coordinate $0$.

[image]

We can see that if the limits exist, it will be extremely unlikely that they will be the same for even and odd $i$; hence why I asked the final part of the question.

I have tried to use @Tianlalu's method as in my previous question. If we define $t=\text{Sa}(x)$ as the inverse function of $y=t\sin t$ on $[0,\pi]$, then $$t\sin t=x\implies t=\text{Sa}(x)$$ If the limit exists, then $$f_\infty=\sin(xf_\infty)\implies xf_\infty\sin(xf_\infty)=xf_\infty^2\implies f_\infty=\frac{\text{Sa}(xf_\infty^2)}x$$ which is not at all useful since we cannot write $f_\infty$ purely in terms of $x$.

Any ideas on how to continue?

Comment: Try a different definition of $\operatorname{Sa}$.

Comment: Establishing the inverse function $$\frac{t}{\sin t}=x\implies t=\text{Sa}(x)$$ would have led to a separable term for $f_{\infty}$:
$$f_{\infty}(x)=\sin(x f_{\infty}(x))\implies \frac{x f_{\infty}(x)}{\sin(x f_{\infty}(x))}=x \implies x f_{\infty}(x) = \text{Sa}(x) \implies f_{\infty}(x) = \frac{\text{Sa}(x)}{x}$$
However, wouldnt have helped since $\frac{y}{\sin{y}}$ is undefined at $y=0$ and $y=\pi$

Comment: Interestingly, swapping out the sines for cosines would lead to an answer, I believe the integral evaluates to the complex number $$(\ln(2)-1)\pi+i \frac{\pi^2}{2}$$

Comment: @StijnDietz, Integrating a real-valued function cannot yield a complex number which is not in $\mathbb{R}$. The usual notion of integral simply does not allow that. Also, replacing $\sin$ by $\cos$ leads to a similar chaotic behavior that I described in my answer, so it is hopeless to expect the integrals converge.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but I still obtained that result. I think I have probably ignored a step which renders the solution invalid

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unlike in the case of iteration $t \mapsto \sin(x+t)$, $f_n(x)$ does not seem converge beyond a certain threshold of $x$. Indeed, plotting the graph of $f_n)$ on $[1,\pi]$ and $201 \leq n \leq 264$ gives

[image]

which clearly demonstrates the chaotic behavior as in the [*logistic map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). This can also be glimpsed by the fact that the iteration $t \mapsto \sin(xt)$ resembles that of the logistic map $t \mapsto x t(1-t)$.

Observe that [*period-doubling cascade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period-doubling_bifurcation) occurs within the interval $[0, \pi]$. That is,

- On the interval of the first bifurcation, $(f_n(x))$ is almost periodic with peroid $2^1 = 2$,
- On the interval of the second bifurcations, $(f_n(x))$ is almost periodic with peroid $2^2 = 4$,

and so on. The following animation visualizes this situation.

$\hspace{3em}$[image: period-doubling cascade]

Thus, unless all the effect of such bifurcations miraculously balance and cancel each other, the values of integrals will oscillate along any subsequences over arithmetic progressions. The graph of $I_k = \int_{0}^{\pi} f_k(x) \, dx $ for $k = 1, \cdots, 100$ seems to support this prediction as well:

$\hspace{5em}$[image: values of integrals]

(Even-th terms are joined by red lines, and odd-th terms are joined by blue lines.)

On the other hand, assuming that $x \in [0, \pi]$ and $f_n(x)$ converges, then its limiting value $f_{\infty}(x)$ admits the following expression

$$ f_{\infty}(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x \geq 1 \\
0, & x < 1 \end{cases}, $$

where $\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}$ is the inverse of the function $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ restricted to $[0, \pi]$. This expression matches the above figure below the threshold.

Comment: (+1) as much as I see your argument, from my graph, it seems that for even increments of $i$, the difference between consecutive values gets smaller and smaller. Although for odd $i$, I cannot see a clear pattern, I think that $L_e$ does have a value.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, I added some extra numerical experiments on the values of integrals.

Comment: Very nice diagrams! Please do take a look at my final one on [Division recurrence of sines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945690/on-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-frac-pi2-sin-left-frac-x-sin-left-frac). I think that one will definitely converge :)

Comment: But do you think that the oscillations will get smaller as you go along, and thus converge to a value?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, My personal impression is that it will not converge. I believe that this oscillation is attributed to the bifurcations that induce $2^k$-period cycles in the values of $f_n$. The only possible way to obtain convergences is that all such cycles miraculously cancel each other in an exact way, which I do not believe to occur...