# On the integral $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x/\sin(x/\sin(x/\sin\cdots)))\,dx$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, regression

This question is the final one out of the set (see [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944265/is-it-true-that-int-0-pi-sinx-sinx-sinx-cdots-dx-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945485/on-the-integral-int-0-pi-sinx-sinx-sinx-cdots-dx)), I promise!

> Consider $f_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f_2(x)=\sin\left(\frac x{f_1(x)}\right)$ such that $f_n$ satisfies the relation $$f_n(x)=\sin\left(\frac x{f_{n-1}(x)}\right).$$ To what value does $$L:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f_{2k-1}(x)\,dx$$ converge, for $k=1,2,\cdots$?

Here is a very nice graph showing the likely convergence of $f_n$:

[image]

The $R^2$ value is extremely close to $1$, and the best fit curve is given by the equation $$y=\frac{0.2091}{e^x-0.5226}+2.411$$ which implies that $$L\approx2.411$$

Are there any analytic techniques to prove this?

Comment: The only thing I am able to spot is that when $n$ is even, $f_{n}(x)$ is an even function, $f_{n}(-x)=f_{n}(x)$. When $n$ is odd, $f_{n}(x)$ is an odd function, $f_{n}(-x)=-f_{n}(x)$. Since the interval is even, the integral of each odd function should evaluate to zero

Comment: I think the answer should be $\frac34\pi$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tianlalu. How do you get this ? It would be very interesting to know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Similar to [$\int_0^\pi\sin(x+\sin(x+\sin(x+\cdots)))\,\mathrm dx=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2944309/394456), we only need to concern the integral on $[0, \pi/2]$ as mentioned by @Stijn Dietz.

Let $\operatorname{Sb}(x)$ be the inverse function of $x\sin x$ on $[0, \pi/2]$ (such function exists by the injectivity). Therefore, 
$$t\sin t =x\implies t=\operatorname{Sb}(x).$$

Assume $f_\infty$ exists (see [2. the third integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2946162/394456)), then
\begin{align*}
f_\infty &= \sin\left(\frac x{f_\infty}\right)\\
x &=\frac x{f_\infty}\sin\left(\frac x{f_\infty}\right)\\
\operatorname{Sb}(x) &=\frac x{f_\infty}\\
f_\infty(x)&=\frac x{\operatorname{Sb}(x)}.
\end{align*}

Thus, using the fact that $\operatorname{Sb(0)}=0$, $\operatorname{Sb\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)}=\dfrac\pi2$ and substituting $x = y\sin y$, $\operatorname{Sb}(x)=y$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2} f_\infty(x)\,\mathrm dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac x{\operatorname{Sb}(x)}\,\mathrm dx\\
& = \int_{\operatorname{Sb}(0)}^{\operatorname{Sb}(\pi/2)} \frac {y\sin y}{y}\,\mathrm d(y\sin y)\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin y(\sin y+y\cos y)\,\mathrm dy\\
& = \frac38\pi.
\end{align*}

> Therefore, 
>   $$L = 2\cdot \frac38\pi = \frac34\pi.$$

Comment: (+1) Well that was simple. I got up to $x/\text{Sb}(x)$ but then I thought it would be impossible to continue due to the fraction. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Very elagant solution for sure $\to +1$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: There was a minor mistake: it should be $\int_{\operatorname{Sb}(0)}^{\operatorname{Sb}(\pi/2)}$ instead of $\int_{0\sin 0}^{\frac\pi2\sin\frac\pi2}$, though there is no change in answer ($\operatorname{Sb}(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{Sb}(\frac\pi2)=\frac\pi2$). So I think we may need to correct the general formula in each case :)